# Android SQLite connection/query error

Tags: java, android, sqlite, intellij-idea

I'm trying to connect SQLite.
Connect method:

```
public void connect() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\..MY_PATH..\\data\\db.sqlite");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
}


public ResultSet query(String sql) throws SQLException
{
    return stmt.executeQuery(sql);
}
```

And after this:

```
ResultSet rs = db.query(sql);
```

It give me an error - I'm trying to run the application, and it not working (tell that there some error in app, but not write the error). For every SQL command. I'm using intelliJ, the editor not give errors.
Maybe the error with connection, but I not understand the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Android does not know what this "C:\" is. You have to use the local filesystem of the android device. I suggest you read up on this topic here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving path in connection try to use

```
localhost / localhost IP
```

For example :

```
(jdbc:mysql:// { localhost/ localhost IP} / Database_Name)
```

And for error :

```
import android.util.Log;
```

Use:

```
Log.e(Tag,"Error : "+ variable_name(You want to console));
```